# Trigger to count child records linked to parent table then inserting value into parent table

Tags: sql, ms-access, triggers, ms-access-2010

```
Parent (licenseID, countChilds)
Child (hostID, licenseID)
```

Trying to write an after insert/update/delete trigger that fires when adding a record to the child table. It needs to count child records linked to the parent and then insert this value into the parent.

*But I keep getting the SQL statement is not valid.*

So far I have this:
[image]

I am using MS Access 2010.

Comment: Why are you storing a value that can be easily calculated with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure you can get away with DCount, for example, this works for me:

[image: data macro]

But I would still recommend not doing this and just getting your counts from a query.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, at least for `After Insert`:

[image: AfterInsert.png]

The `After Update` Data Macro would be a bit more involved because it might have to update two [License] records (one for [Host].[licenseID] and another for [Old].[licenseID]), or perhaps none (if [Host].[licenseID] did not change).

Comment: For some reason, when I tried your solution, the field was not being updated with the new count variable. Not sure why cause your solution looks like it should work..